# Proptypes children of type component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to proptype to a specific component class with type Input but its giving me a waring.

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to
>   `MyComponent`.

**MyComponent.js**

```
    import React, { Component, cloneElement } from 'react';
    import Input from '../Input';

    class MyComponent extends Component {
      static propTypes = {
        children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
          PropTypes.shape({
            type: PropTypes.oneOf([Input]),
          }),
          PropTypes.arrayOf(
            PropTypes.shape({
              type: PropTypes.oneOf([Input]),
            })
          ),
        ]).isRequired,
      }

      renderChildren(child) {
        const clone = cloneElement(child, {newProp: 'blaaa'});
        return <div className='inner'>{clone}</div>;
      }

      render() {
        const { children } = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
            {React.Children.map(children, this.renderChildren)}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

export default MyComponent;
```

**My Input Component stripped down.**

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

const Input = ({name}) => (
    <Fragment>
      <input
      />
    </Fragment>
);

export default Input;
```

**Console log on the children is:**

```
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
key: null
props: {id: "email", placeholder: "email", type: "tel", name: "Email", styles: Array(1), …}
ref: null
type: ƒ Input(_ref)
_owner: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: "inputname", type: ƒ, stateNode: null, return: FiberNode, …}
_self: null
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you provide a `console.log(this.props.children)` in all of its variations/use cases.

Comment: Just added the console log in my edited post above at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes your `MyComponent` will be consistent in receiving one or more React `Input`s.

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/045kw2pq30

**component/NonInput.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const NonInput = props => (
  <code>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 4)}</pre>
  </code>
);

NonInput.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
};

export default NonInput;
```

**components/Input.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const Input = ({ newProp, ...props }) => (
  <Fragment>
    {console.log(newProp)}
    <input className="uk-input" {...props} />
  </Fragment>
);

Input.propTypes = {
  newProp: PropTypes.string,
  props: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.string)
};

export default Input;
```

**components/MyComponent.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent, cloneElement } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Input from "./Input";

const shapeOfChildren = PropTypes.shape({
  type: PropTypes.oneOf([Input]).isRequired,
  props: PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired
});

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  renderChildren = child => (
    <div className="inner">{cloneElement(child, { newProp: "blaaa" })}</div>
  );

  render = () => (
    <div className="uk-form-large">
      {React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChildren)}
    </div>
  );
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    shapeOfChildren,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(shapeOfChildren)
  ]).isRequired
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**components/Example.js** (remove the `NonInput`, save, then refresh the page to remove the PropType warning -- if you want it to display a more definitive warning, then write a [custom validator function (example toward the bottom)](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types#usage))

```
import React from "react";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";
import Input from "./Input";
import NonInput from "./NonInput";

export default () => (
  <MyComponent>
    <Input name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
    <Input name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <NonInput name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
  </MyComponent>
);
```

Comment: Thanks Matt but node implies Anything can be rendered as a child: numbers, strings, elements or an array(or fragment). I don't want anything to be a rendered. I specifically only want Input component be children to be rendered.

Comment: In that case, replace `node` with `Input`'s `shape`

Comment: But thats what I have in my example and I'm getting a warning ? Can you give me an example of Input shape that's different from mine

Comment: PropTypes.shape({
              type: PropTypes.oneOf([Input]),
            })

Comment: I'm not at my computer at the moment,  but basically you would copy the structure of what you provided above in `console.log(this.props.children)`.

Comment: Right and my post has that. type: ƒ Input(_ref)

Comment: type: PropTypes.oneOf([Input]),

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: On a related note, you can skip this superfluous validation. Since you're expecting it to always be an `Input` component, there's no need to pass it as a child. Instead, just pass `props` to `MyComponent` and append/clone them to an `Input`. This would make more sense and be easier to test against.

Comment: Thank you for the full example.